# Use karate-config.js with standalone jar?

Tags: karate

I have a karate-config.js file:

```
function init() {
  karate.log("Env set to ", karate.env);
  karate.log("baseURL ", karate.properties["baseURL"]);
  karate.log("OriginURl", karate.properties["OriginURL"]);

  return {
    foo: "bar"
  };
}
```

and I'm running using the standalone karate.jar:

```
amzuko@DESKTOP-V0PECAR:/mnt/c/Joincad/komodo$ java -jar  bin/karate.jar path/to/my/feature
16:42:53.943 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.netty.Main - Karate version: 0.9.0
16:42:54.054 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - Karate version: 0.9.0
16:42:54.849 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] WARN  com.intuit.karate - not a js function or feature file: read('file:./karate-config.js') - [type: NULL, value: null]
...
```

I see the same "not a js function or feature file: read('file:./karate-config.js') - [type: NULL, value: null]" error message whether I set the karate.config path explicitly or not. If I set the karate.config.path value to a directory that does not contain a karate-config.js file,

I'm running this primarily on the windows subsystem for linux. I get identical results (modulo needing to swap back and forward slashes in the paths) when I run using git-bash and powershell in the windows environment directly.

My project structure is, where the working directory is '/':

```
/services/tests/*.feature  <<-- features here
/bin/karate.jar
/karate-config.js
```

I'm using karate to test an API implemented in golang. I've tried with 0.8.1 and 0.9.0.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you update your question with your project structure? I tried with karate-0.9.0 standalone, tried to execute it using WSL and its working fine for me

Comment: alse refer this ticket discussion, there are some additional fixes in the develop branch. would be great to get them tested before we release 0.9.1 https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/624

Comment: Thanks @BabuSekaran, I've updated the question with my (very simple) project structure.

Comment: @PeterThomas Thank you for the pointer to that issue; I had perused a few others, but not found that one. I'm not sure that it's related (the error I see is not that karate cannot find the karate-config.js), but I'm up to give the dev branch a shot! Are the development branch builds available anywhere by chance? I couldn't find them clicking around the build server.

Comment: @yurbles not released yet, but should be very easy to build yourself, please refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas, totally works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be related in some way to the fix for https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/624, and as of 1/7/2019, using a .jar built from the develop branch of karate resolved my problems.